# Approximating distribution and delta method

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, approximation-theory

Suppose i.i.d r.v $X$ has density of $\frac{3x+1}{8}$ on interval $(0,2)$, define $Y = \pi X^2$. Questions are:

1. If $Z = \pi \bar{X}^2$, where $\bar{X}$ is arithmetic mean of all $X_s$
2. If $\bar{Y}$ defined to be arithmetic mean of all $Y_s$

For question 1, we could find the approximate distribution of $Z$ using CLT and Delta method. For question 2, we could also find the approximate distribution of $\bar{Y}$.

Will these two be the same in the end? Why or why not?

Thanks!

Comment: You should expect these to be quite different basically because of Jensen's inequality, which in this context reads $E[X^2] \geq E[X]^2$.

Comment: you mean the approximate mean, okay, got it. Thanks

Comment: Well no, I was talking about the real mean. But this effect is reflected in the distribution of the square of the sample mean vs. that of the sample mean of the squares, too.

Comment: Yep, got you. Thanks a lot!